# How to work with down arrow key in Auto Suggest Box?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, autosuggest

In my Auto Suggest box when i am pressing down arrow in suggestion list then suggestion list is getting closed automatically in no time.

I want to keep open the list until user presses Enter key.
This is my XAML code

```
<AutoSuggestBox x:Name="recipient" KeyUp="recipient_KeyDown" FontSize="18" Height="50" TextChanged="recipient_TextChanged" SuggestionChosen="recipient_SuggestionChosen" x:Uid="recipienttextplaceholder" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,20,0,0" Style="{StaticResource AutoSuggestBoxStyle2}">
                    <AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="firstName" Visibility="{Binding FirstName, Converter={StaticResource NullOrWhiteSpaceConverter}}" TextAlignment="Left"/>

                                <TextBlock Text="|" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,-10,0" Visibility="{Binding Visibility,ElementName=middleName}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MiddleName}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Visibility="{Binding MiddleName, Converter={StaticResource NullOrWhiteSpaceConverter}}" x:Name="middleName" Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Left"/>

                                <TextBlock Text="|" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding Visibility,ElementName=lastName}" Margin="0,0,-6,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" Margin="10,0,0,0" x:Name="lastName" Visibility="{Binding LastName, Converter={StaticResource NullOrWhiteSpaceConverter}}" Grid.Column="2" TextAlignment="Left"/>

                                <!--<TextBlock Text="|" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,0,-6,0" Visibility="{Binding Visibility,ElementName=lastName}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>-->
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate>
                </AutoSuggestBox>
```

TextChanged event:

```
private void recipient_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (sender.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            recipient.ItemsSource = new List<string>();
            return;
        }
        var recipientFilteredByPersonData = new List<Table_People>();
        var recipientFilteredByPlace = new List<Table_Places>();

        if (PeopleList != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in PeopleList)
            {
                if (item.FirstName.Contains(sender.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || item.MiddleName.Contains(sender.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || item.LastName.Contains(sender.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    item.Icon = "../Assets/user_profile.png";
                    recipientFilteredByPersonData.Add(item);
                }
            }
            cvrbyperson.Source = recipientFilteredByPersonData.OrderBy(x => x.FirstName).GroupBy(x => x.FirstName[0]).ToList();
            //recipient.ItemsSource = recipientFilteredByPersonData;
        }

        if (PlacesList != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in PlacesList)
            {
                if (item.AccountNumber.Contains(sender.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || item.Name.Contains(sender.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    item.Icon = "../Assets/ic_location.png";
                    recipientFilteredByPlace.Add(item);
                }
            }
            cvrbyplace.Source = recipientFilteredByPlace.OrderBy(x => x.FirstName).GroupBy(x => x.FirstName[0]).ToList();
            //recipient.ItemsSource = recipientFilteredByPlace;
        }
        List<object> combinePlacePerson = (from x in recipientFilteredByPersonData select (object)x).ToList();
        combinePlacePerson.AddRange((from x in recipientFilteredByPlace select (object)x).ToList());
        if (combinePlacePerson.Count == 0)
        {
            var noResults = new List<Table_People>();
            var resultWithNoItem = new Table_People { FirstName = "No results." };
            noResults.Add(resultWithNoItem);
            recipient.ItemsSource = noResults;
        }
        else
        {
            recipient.ItemsSource = combinePlacePerson;
        }
    }
```

Suggestion Chosen event:

```
 private void recipient_SuggestionChosen(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionChosenEventArgs args)
    {
        var getType = args.SelectedItem.GetType();
        if (getType.Name == "Table_People")
        {
            var selectedItemRecipient = args.SelectedItem as Table_People;
            sender.Text = selectedItemRecipient.FirstName + " " + selectedItemRecipient.LastName;
            recipienterror.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            _personID = selectedItemRecipient.PersonID;
        }
        else
        {
            var selectedItemRecipientPlaces = args.SelectedItem as Table_Places;
            _placeID = selectedItemRecipientPlaces.PlaceID;
            sender.Text = selectedItemRecipientPlaces.FirstName + " " + selectedItemRecipientPlaces.LastName;
            recipienterror.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

    }
```

I am setting the ItemsSource from the code.Do i need to handle the KeUp event or not?

```
private void recipient_KeyUp(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Down)
        {
            recipient.IsSuggestionListOpen = true;
        }
    }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Which control has focus when you press the down key, AutoSuggestBox or suggestion list?

Comment: Suggestion List.

Comment: Not able to reproduce your issue, created a simple app with an `AutoSuggestBox`. Both Up and Down keys work when the focus switches to the suggestion list, without any extra code for keyboard handling. Can you post the code showing how you open the suggestion list?

Comment: I am setting the ItemsSource of the control on TextChanged event.

Comment: How are you handling `SuggestionChosen` event ?

Comment: @ravikumar: Added the suggestion chosen event in the question.

Comment: The reason is that i am setting the text of my Auto Suggest control in the SuggestionChosen event.If i comment it out then it is behaving properly but now the real problem is that if i make a suggestion then however i need to show the text on the control.How do i show it?

Comment: @tushargoyal1309 Do you have solution for this?

Answer (score -2):

That might be help you. I used it on Windows Forms `ComboBox`

```
private void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) MessageBox.Show("hello");
}
```

Comment: This is not winforms.